# BS4 for HTML with special chars

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need some help, for a project I should have to parse information from a real estate website.

Somehow I am able to parse almost, everything, but it has a oneliner, which I've never seen before.

The code itself is too large, but some example snippet:

```
<div class="d-none" data-listing='{"strippedPhotos":[{"caption":"","description":"","urls":{"1920x1080":"https:\/\/ot.ingatlancdn.com\/d6\/07\/32844921_216401477_hd.jpg","800x600":"https:\/\/ot.ingatlancdn.com\/d6\/07\/32844921_216401477_l.jpg","228x171":"https:\/\/ot.ingatlancdn.com\/d6\/07\/32844921_216401477_m.jpg","80x60":"https:\/\/ot.ingatlancdn.com\/d6\/07
```

Can you please help me to identify this, and maybe a solution to how to parse all the contained info into a `pandas` DF?

Edit, code added:

```
other = []
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
site= "https://ingatlan.com/xiii-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32844921"
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

data = soup.find_all('div', id="listing", class_="d-none", attrs="data-listing")

data
```

Comment: You have not posted any information relevant to the question.

Put as you already tried (your code), the expected result, make it reproducible so that we can help.

Comment: Hi, I just added the code which I'm using to parse the data, and where I'm stuck

Comment: Thanks @B_ottoman , this way you will be able to find help much easier, because now everyone has a view of the case and where to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the value of the attribute and convert the string via `json.loads()`:

```
data = json.loads(soup.find('div', id="listing", class_="d-none", attrs="data-listing").get('data-listing'))
```

Then simply create your `DataFrame` via `pandas.json_normalize()`:

```
pd.json_normalize(data['strippedPhotos'])
```

###### Example

Cause expected result is not clear, this just should point in a direction:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd
import json

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
site= "https://ingatlan.com/xiii-ker/elado+lakas/tegla-epitesu-lakas/32844921"
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

data = json.loads(soup.find('div', id="listing", class_="d-none", attrs="data-listing").get('data-listing'))

###  all data
pd.json_normalize(data)
### only strippedPhotos
pd.json_normalize(data['strippedPhotos'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you just solved the biggest problem with my project. :)